# Прочитать определённую строку из txt файла [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как я могу прочитать одну определённую строку из txt файла используя пакет `fs`(лучше бы записать значение в переменную)?
Например,         txt файл:
   first
second
 third

Из этого файла мне нужно "вытащить" и записать 2-ю строку(`second`) в переменную. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочитать файл можно в асинхронном режиме (метод **readFile**) либо синхронном (метод **readFileSync**). Это может выглядеть так (в примерах подключаете модуль **fs**, указываете свой путь к файлу).

Асинхронный вариант:

```
let line;
fs.readFile('./file.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    line = data.split('\n')[1]);
});
```

Синхронный вариант:

```
const str = fs.readFileSync('./file.txt', 'utf8');
const line = str.split('\n')[1];
```